# Cannot start MySQL under CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, mysql-error-1064

I have got installed MySQL by default in CentOS 7. It is allowed to start with Firewall and etc.

But I cannot start it using

```
sudo /sbin/service mysqld start
```

Error

> ...No search file or directory

All links about this subject dont help.

Any clue how to start it?

P.S. I found where is mysqld but when I start it I see many errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is `service` in sbin? `whereis service` and try again...

Comment: @MarcB whell... When I do like `whereis mysqld` it returns `mysqld: /usr/libexec/mysqld`

Comment: who said anything about mysql? sudo is unable to find `/sbin/service`. it's not even getting to the mysql bit yet.

Comment: @MarcB This page says it http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-mysql-server-on-centos Any clue how to start MySQL?

Comment: just run `whereis service`. c'mon... obviously their guide is wrong, or your system is configured differntly.

Comment: @MarcB Well. it shows `service: /usr/sbin/service` Take  alook at my updated question, please.

Comment: CentOS and all RedHat derivative started using `systemd` since version 7.0. You should start `mysqld` using `systemctl start mysqld.service`. Starting `mysqld` on it's own will not work because it lacks needed parameters such as where the configuration file is.

Comment: @MarcB When I start it  like this it says that there is no file or directory  :( I just added a new screenshot, check it, please.

Comment: Seeing that you are using `MariaDB` your service name may have been changed to `mariadb`. If you still attempt to run `sudo /usr/sbin/service start mariadb` it should automatically redirect to `systemctl start mariadb.service`.

Comment: The new screenshot you posted shows that it's running.

Comment: In the screenshot above you tried to start it with your user instead of root - e.g. sudo. Still would be completely wrong way to start it - for what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered MariaDB was not installed properly.

Once it is installed I could access via mysql.